# Thumbnails not showing in video in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: video, thumbnails

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I've manually installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
Everything looks fine except video thumbnails.
How to solve this?

Comment: Did you choose the "minimal installation" option instead of "normal installation" as shown here: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/the-ubuntu-minimal-install-option.jpg?

Comment: I choose normal installation.

Comment: Upgraded to ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04 recently, same issue no thumbnails in my list view of folders and never checked icon view. I did everything except for some commonsense then bumped on following https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/8di3ce/no_file_thumbnails_in_1804_list_view/ and that seems to be my issue, icon view thumbnails always work and in list view I need to zoom to 150%.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Install **FFMPEG Thumbnailer**-

```
sudo apt install ffmpegthumbnailer
```

Then close and reopen file manager. Thumbnails for most video files should generate now.

However, if it's still not working then open file manager, go to your home folder if you're not already there (Home folder is usually the folder which contains Downloads, Documents, Photos etc folders).

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, enter into the folder named **.cache**. Then enter in the folder **thumbnails**.
 Delete everything in there. Restart your PC.

Comment: No need to restart my PC; quitting and restarting Nautilus was enough

Comment: Alternatively you can run-

`rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails/*` 

in Terminal to clear the thumbnail cache.

Comment: already installed. in my case, some mp4 files have thumbnails, others do not.  file size limit is 4096MB, which is larger than any of my files...

Comment: Installing `ffmpegthumbnailer` works for Ubuntu 20.04. Thumbnails were displayed immediately in the Nautilus window that was already opened.

Comment: This worked for me on Arch as well with PCManFM with just a restart of it.

Comment: Did this with nautilus closed, then opened it after installation, worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I had to disable the totem thumbnailer in the `/usr/share/thumbnailers` to make it work.

Comment: Didn't work for me (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64 )

Comment: @HattinGokbori87 Hey your trick for clearing out the thumbnail cache, thanks, that's a nice trick I keep coming back to it time and time again. I hope you post that more often so more people can be exposed to it, it's so much easier than manually clearing out the thumbnail cache you know what I'm sayin'?

Answer (score 49):

I have tried [HattinGokbori87's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034596) but it failed, and I found another way to solve it.

First I installed the HattinGokbori87's suggested package like this:

```
sudo apt install ffmpegthumbnailer
```

Then I restarted the computer but I still could not see the video's thumbnails in the file manager, so I tried to install another package like this:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

Then cleaned up the directory like this:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail
```

Then **reopen** the file manager, it works!

Refer to [this article](http://logan.tw/posts/2015/11/08/fix-nautilus-video-thumbnails/) if your Ubuntu 18.04 thumbnails still do not work.

**Update:** For Ubuntu 20.04 this method still works (I just upgraded my computer operating system from Ubuntu 19.10 to Ubuntu 20.04).

**Update (2023-2-8):** For Ubuntu 22.04 and Pop!_OS 22.04, this method still works.

Comment: This is working solution for Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks.

Comment: Working in Ubuntu 23.10

Answer (score 1):

Install following packages

ffmpeg,ffmpegthumbnailer,gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg ffmpegthumbnailer gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Then edit the following file with respective content

```
sudo vi /usr/share/thumbnailers/totem.thumbnailer
```

just paste the following lines

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=ffmpegthumbnailer
Exec=ffmpegthumbnailer -s %s -i %i -o %o -c png -f -t 10
MimeType=application/mxf;application/ogg;application/ram;application/sdp;application/vnd.ms-wpl;application/vnd.rn-realmedia;application/x-extension-m4a;application/x-extension-mp4;application/x-flash-video;application/x-matroska;application/x-netshow-channel;application/x-ogg;application/x-quicktimeplayer;application/x-shorten;image/vnd.rn-realpix;image/x-pict;misc/ultravox;text/x-google-video-pointer;video/3gpp;video/dv;video/fli;video/flv;video/mp2t;video/mp4;video/mp4v-es;video/mpeg;video/msvideo;video/ogg;video/quicktime;video/vivo;video/vnd.divx;video/vnd.rn-realvideo;video/vnd.vivo;video/webm;video/x-anim;video/x-avi;video/x-flc;video/x-fli;video/x-flic;video/x-flv;video/x-m4v;video/x-matroska;video/x-mpeg;video/x-ms-asf;video/x-ms-asx;video/x-msvideo;video/x-ms-wm;video/x-ms-wmv;video/x-ms-wmx;video/x-ms-wvx;video/x-nsv;video/x-ogm+ogg;video/x-theora+ogg;video/x-totem-stream;audio/x-pn-realaudio;audio/3gpp;audio/ac3;audio/AMR;audio/AMR-WB;audio/basic;audio/midi;audio/mp2;audio/mp4;audio/mpeg;audio/ogg;audio/prs.sid;audio/vnd.rn-realaudio;audio/x-aiff;audio/x-ape;audio/x-flac;audio/x-gsm;audio/x-it;audio/x-m4a;audio/x-matroska;audio/x-mod;audio/x-mp3;audio/x-mpeg;audio/x-ms-asf;audio/x-ms-asx;audio/x-ms-wax;audio/x-ms-wma;audio/x-musepack;audio/x-pn-aiff;audio/x-pn-au;audio/x-pn-wav;audio/x-pn-windows-acm;audio/x-realaudio;audio/x-real-audio;audio/x-sbc;audio/x-speex;audio/x-tta;audio/x-wav;audio/x-wavpack;audio/x-vorbis;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;audio/x-xm;application/x-flac;
```

and finally restart your machine and see.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1988100) either in `totem-video-thumbnailer` or `GStreamer`.

When you search for solutions, many of them suggest `ffmpegthumbnailer`.

I can't say whether it's a better, or a worse thumbnailer, but installing it *did* work for me.

The only caveat is that you seem to have to configure configure things to override the system default. I couldn't find what the default processing order is for conflicting thumbnailers in the same directory, but thumbnailers in `~/.local/share/thumbnailers` appear to take precedence over `/usr/share/thumbnailers`

Creating a link solved my problem:

`ln -s /usr/share/thumbnailers/ffmpegthumbnailer.thumbnailer ~/.local/share/thumbnailers/ffmpegthumbnailer.thumbnailer`

### A couple of notes:

1. Here is an excellent answer with a *swag* of background about [how thumbnailing hangs together](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368910/how-to-create-custom-thumbnailers-for-nautilus-nemo-and-caja)
2. You may quit nautilus/nemo by running them with the -q flag

   ```
   $nautilus -q
   $nemo -q
   ```
3. Deleting the contents of `~/.cache/thumbnails` causes thumbnails to be rebuilt the next time they are needed

Answer (score 0):

Use `ffmpeg` by creating a thumbnailer entry that invokes `ffmpeg`. The thumbnailer will run for MIME types `video/mp4` and `video/webm`, but additional types can be added as desired.

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg 
echo -e "[Thumbnailer Entry]\nTryExec=ffmpeg\nExec=ffmpeg -i %i -vf thumbnail,scale=\"256:-1\" -frames:v 1 %o\nMimeType=video/mp4;video/webm" | sudo tee /usr/share/thumbnailers/custom-ffmpeg.thumbnailer
rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails/*
nohup nautilus -q > /dev/null &
```

Answer (score -1):

I followed HattinGokbori87's instructions above, that is:

```
sudo apt install ffmpegthumbnailer
```

Then delete thumbnail cache and restart

This fixed my issue, which was that only some mp4 files have thumbnails. However, it also removed existing mpeg thumbnails.

So, I remove ffmpegthumbnailer:

```
sudo apt remove ffmpegthumbnailer
```

Then delete thumbnail cache and restart

And it works, I guess all I really needed to do was delete the cache and restart.