# Video Thumbnails Maker for Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, windows, video, thumbnails

I need a program which can generate video thumbnails (not a single, but picture with rows and columns of video track) into a jpeg file. Currently I have to run Win7 as vm machine with shared folders, I use there "Video Thumbnails Maker by SUU Design" (you can google for it).
I need to create smth like [this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/75d916a6a1cb89e5dd818a44664a47f27a39bec6/687474703a2f2f697069632e73752f696d672f66732f4269674275636b42756e6e792e313532383430343836352e6a7067)
Is there any good GUI-enabled Linux tool for thumbnails creation? Please help me, otherwise everyday I am getting back to Windows.

Comment: Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034595/thumbnails-not-showing-in-video-in-ubuntu-18-04) for possible answer.

Comment: sorry, this is not what i need

Comment: You could try https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezthumb/ which uses ffmpeg