# video thumbnails not showing in 20.10, HattinGokbori87 solution doesnt work

Tags: nautilus, video, 20.10, thumbnails

How to get video thumbnails to show in Ubuntu 20.10?

I tried this solution [Thumbnails not showing in video in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034595/thumbnails-not-showing-in-video-in-ubuntu-18-04) but
does not work for 20.10

I currenty can see pdf and jpg thumbnails but not video thumbnails.

Any solution please?

Answer (score 11):

The answer is here https://askubuntu.com/a/1080512/740291 thanks to Hatsune which is slightly different to HattinGokbori87 solution...

```
sudo apt install ffmpegthumbnailer
```

Then I restarted the computer but I still could not see the video's thumbnails in the file manager, so I tried to install another package like this:
(edit: this is the important part to get it working for Ubuntu 20.10)

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

Then cleaned up the directory like this:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail
```

Re-opened the Ubuntu file manager, it works!

Update: For Ubuntu 20.04 this method still applies (I just upgraded my computer operating system from Ubuntu 19.10 to Ubuntu 20.04).
edit: This works for 20.10 also.

Comment: this worked in 20.04 also. thanks

Comment: this worked in 22.04 also. thanks